# Удалить цифры с конца строки до первой буквы

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Есть строки:

```
dsds444dhhdhshhdhs1233
dd33ssddsdsdhs332
dsd777hhjjhs1233
```

Нужно удалить цифры с конца строки до первой буквы. И результат:

```
dsds444dhhdhshhdhs
dd33ssddsdsdhs
dsd777hhjjhs
```

Делаю вот так но удаляются все цифры:

```
for i:=length(s) downto 1 do
if not(s[i] in ['0'..'9']) then delete(s,i);
```

Comment: @Эникейщик, Спасибо за подсказку. Ответила на вопрос благодаря Вам.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на вопрос:

```
for i:=length(s) downto 1 do
if s[i] in ['0'..'9'] then delete(s,i) 
// То есть выход из цикла если не цифра
else Break;
```